# How to check if app is open in another tab for Reactjs App

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a react app, and I want the user won't be able to open the app in another tab if the app already opened it in another tab. something like WhatsApp https://i.stack.imgur.com/PL9WU.jpg.

Is there any way to detect if the app already opens in another tab?

Comment: Not something you can do trivially, and probably not portably.

Comment: I've not tried, but you might try firestore. When component renders, increment a field in firestore in a collection. When component unmounts, you decrement that field.

Comment: WhatsApp web does this by establishing a socket connection to the server; just do the same thing.

Comment: @ChrisG that is indeed the correct answer, but you're making that sound a lot easier than it is. How is the OP going to keep track of what user has an open session? Stuff it in a database? Memcache?

Comment: Muhammed Taseen, you may want to rethink whether or not you really want to do this. Why do you need this feature?

Comment: If you want to be sure, you'll have to implement this server-side. When a user opens a second session (from another tab/device), invalidate the existing one and inform the client (via sse, websocket or what have you)

Comment: Thanks to all, I've done this with localStorage + React custom hook. you guys can see the example here - https://m407l.csb.app/

Comment: i'll be happy if anyone suggest me the batter way or improve my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

I'm answering my own question, I've done this successfully. I've created a custom react hook to force my app to open on a single tab.

I'll improve my code soon but for now, this working fine for me.

see the example: https://m407l.csb.app/

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

const useIsMainWindow = () => {
  const initialized = useRef(false);
  const isNewWindowPromotedToMain = useRef(false);
  const windowId = useRef(null);
  const [isMain, setIsMain] = useState(true);

  const getWindowArray = () => {
    let storage = window.localStorage.getItem("checkTab");
    return storage ? JSON.parse(storage) : [];
  };

  const setWindowArray = (data) => {
    window.localStorage.setItem("checkTab", JSON.stringify(data));
  };

  const determineWindowState = () => {
    let windowArray = getWindowArray();

    if (initialized.current) {
      if (
        windowArray.length <= 1 ||
        (isNewWindowPromotedToMain.current
          ? windowArray[windowArray.length - 1]
          : windowArray[0]) === windowId.current
      ) {
        setIsMain(true);
      } else {
        setIsMain(false);
      }
    } else {
      if (windowArray.length === 0) {
        setIsMain(true);
      } else {
        setIsMain(false);
      }
      const newWindowArray = [...windowArray, windowId.current];
      setWindowArray(newWindowArray);
    }

    setTimeout(function () {
      determineWindowState();
    }, 1500);
  };

  const removeWindow = () => {
    var newWindowArray = getWindowArray();
    for (var i = 0, length = newWindowArray.length; i < length; i++) {
      if (newWindowArray[i] === windowId.current) {
        newWindowArray.splice(i, 1);
        break;
      }
    }
    setWindowArray(newWindowArray);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", removeWindow);
    window.addEventListener("unload", removeWindow);
    isNewWindowPromotedToMain.current = true;
    windowId.current = Date.now().toString();
    determineWindowState();
    initialized.current = true;

    () => {
      window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", removeWindow);
      window.removeEventListener("unload", removeWindow);
    };
  }, []);

  return isMain;
};

export default useIsMainWindow;
```